# Does SSIS always respect the ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a data flow containing a data source and data destination.  The data source has the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Person ORDER BY ID
```

There are millions of rows and it takes several hours to transfer the data.  Say the process fails after a few hours and SSIS tells me 1,067,987 of 3,678,543 rows were transferred - can I assume that the max(ID) will be 1,067,987?

Does SSIS always respect the order by clause?

I have spent an hour or so Googling this and I have not found an answer - hence the reason for the question.

Please note that this query returns 1,067,987 rows in the source database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person where ID <=1067987
```

Comment: *"Does SSIS always respect the order by clause?"* -  I would say yes, because not SSIS is ordering the rows, but the source (here: SQL Server) is. Sorting data is a separate processing step in SSIS that you have to add explicitly. If you don't, source order is retained.

Comment: Also, if running an ORDER BY query over table with a million rows takes hours, you're clearly missing a (clustered) index on the source table.

Comment: If the ID is in the source, does it start at one and has no gaps? What's the real problem here?

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks.  The source query runs in a few seconds.  The time constraint is due to transferring the data.  It would be good to see this documented somewhere.

Comment: Are you transferring data from SQL Server to SQL Server? There are probably quicker ways

Comment: @Tomalak, if the process fails; I want to know where to start again from (instead of starting from the beginning) e.g. in the case of my scenario; the source query would change to: SELECT * FROM Person where ID >1067987

Comment: Well I can't point out documentation, but SSIS does not apply any sorting of its own unless you explicitly tell it to. It does not even *see* the ORDER BY, that's just part of the query text it sends to the SQL Server. I don't see any chance of randomization here - SSIS takes what SQL Server sends to it. If you query with `TOP 1067987` in the SSMS and the last ID is what you expect it to be, then there is no reason to assume that it won't be so in SSIS.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, yes it is SQL Server top SQLServer

Comment: SSIS supports restarting interrupted transactions. See [checkpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/restart-packages-by-using-checkpoints).

Comment: Same DB or different? Are you transforming the data or just copying it over? There might be quicker more reliable ways to do this

Comment: As for "quicker ways" - Established a linked server, run `INSERT INTO local_table SELECT * FROM other_server.db_name.schema.table`

Comment: @Tomalak, A linked server is not an option because it is a third party vendor (source).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, different databases on different servers (one external server).

Comment: I don't know what the hold up is in your SSIS package, but `BCP -n` can be faster and easier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15